# Http client with get request

Tags: python, http, client, cython

Quick question: need pure python script of simple http client without using libs (only socket library possible).

Main task of this client is connect to server, receive greetings, sends get requests and read responses. Also it's good if this code will be compatible with Cython compiler.

Comment: Good luck writing the script, let us know if you get stuck or need help

Comment: Thanks for everybody attention. I figure out that I've just required the content of get and post requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you using `requests` https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests package.

But your question looks like an assignment which shall teach you how is http working on TCP communication level. In such case I would recommend you

- learn using http protocol over telnet or netcat
- then learn TCP communication by Python and repeat, what you already know by telnet